# Prevent Admin type user to edit same forms same time

Tags: laravel

While a Admin Type user edit a customer profile ( i.e: customer ID: 23 ), prevent another admin to edit that same customer. How this can be done in Laravel ?

I am finding the best way to do it instead of heavy server load

Comment: You do it by programming some logic.

Comment: Explain better@kazi.. you want to prevent at the same time 2 admins edit? or one edit and later other can't? Bring some code

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

1. craete an `is_editing` flag on the model that prevents other users from editing the resource. Your controller would look something like this:

```
public function edit(Model $model) {
    $model->update(['is_editing'=>true]);
    return view(....);
}

public function store(Model $model) {
    if ($model->is_editing) { abort(....); }
    $model->update(...);
}
```

2. Check for optimistic concurrency. I won't give a code example for this one, but basically, you encode the current values of the form when it is sent to the user. When the user hits update, you compare the current values from the DB to the set that you sent with the form. If they don't match, you assume that someone has modified the form in the interim.